# MongoDB db.collection.save overwrite object when existing

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, you can use `db.collection.save({_id:'abc'}, objectToSave)` to perform an upsert.

Let's define objectToSave as below

```
{_id:'abc', field1:1, field2:2};
```

In my collection, I have already have a document with same _id value as below:

```
{_id:'abc', field3:3};
```

The save function above will replace the existing document in collection to

```
{_id:'abc', field1:1, field2:2};
```

What I want is to perform a $set operation to produce some document in collection as below

```
{_id:'abc', field1:1, field2:2, field3:3};
```

Can this be achieved in the save function or I have to write separate update statements?

Note that objectToSave's fields are dynamic. The language I'm using is Node.JS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({'_id':'abc'},{$set:{field1:1,field2:2}},{upsert:true})
```

should do what you want:

1. It upserts, so if the document does not exist yet, it is created as `{_id:'abc',field1:1,field2:2}` and efficiently so, since an index is used which must exist
2. If the document already exists, the fields field1 and field2 are set to the value in the update statement.
3. If either of the fields exist in the document, it will be overwritten.

Since you didn't state what language you use: in plain mongoDB, there is no `save` function. The explicit requirement to merge new and persisted versions of entities is quite an unusual one, so yes, I'd assume that you have to write a custom function.

Comment: Markus, I forgot to mention one thing, the list of fields in objectToSave is undetermined. So I can't use update and $set with specific fields. I'm using Node.JS.

Comment: Why that? You can use set on an arbitrary number of fields. Create an according object, pass it as the value for `$set` and you are good to go.

Comment: objectToSave has an _id field and that _id value is not confirmed to be existing in collection. $set won't allow an update on _id field.

Comment: So you have to remove that Id from the object, store it in a variable (which you need for the query anyway) and shoot the upsert as described.

Comment: If I remove the _id, then I'll lose its value if Mongo decide to insert the object. It will generate a new _id.

Comment: Additional point, I don't know what you mean by plain MongoDB. If you are referring to MongoDB shell, save is available.

Comment: And it's not unusual to merge new and persisted version. In fact, the main point is not about merging but to avoid overwriting persisted version unintentionally.

Comment: Well, I assume you will find out. You won't loose it, since you will query for it, and an upset is intelligent enough to take the ID you queried for. a `db.test.update({_id:"efg"},{$set:{field1:1,field2:2}},{upsert:true})` leads to the creation of *drummroll* `{ "_id" : "efg", "field1" : 1, "field2" : 2 }`. But I guess it's easier to be a smarty pant than to simply try the advice given.

Comment: Sorry, Markus. I don't know how I formed the wrong impression about the upsert. Thanks again for correcting me on that.